# Proof of that f is integrable

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Suppose that $\phi$ is continuously differentiable on $[a,b]$ and $f$ is integrable on $[c,d]:=\phi[a,b]$. If $\phi'$ is never zero on $[a,b]$, then prove that $f (\phi)$  is integrable on $[a,b]$.

Ok, so I can see that this is basically the same premise as the change of variable formula, so it's obvious that $$\int^{b}_{a} f(\phi(x)) |\phi'|dx$$ and also that $f(\phi)$ is integrable on $[c,d]$, but I am having trouble showing that $f(\phi)$ is integrable on $[a,b]$. Is there some theorem about integrals that states that if some $fg$ is integrable on an interval that $f$ and $g$ individually are integrable on that interval?

Comment: Please [take a look at how I've edited your MathJax code](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/cc973fbc-aeaf-47cb-9d9b-1a8226a40760/view-source); I encourage you to emulate it. In particular, each "stretch" of mathematics should be in one piece of MathJax. For example, instead of writing something like `$a$ $\otimes$ $b$`, you should write `$a\otimes b$`. You can find some good starting points on how to format mathematics on the site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020). [This AMS reference](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) is very useful.

Comment: Is this Riemann or Lebesgue integration?

Comment: Reimann integration

Answer (score 1):

About your last question, the answer is no. Multiply any non-integrable function by $0$ and you will get $0$, which is integrable.

**Fact:** if $f$ and $g$ are Riemann-integrable over $[a,b]$, then so is their pointwise product $fg$.

As you noted, the function $(f\circ \phi) \cdot\phi'$ is integrable over $[a,b]$ by change of variable.

On the other hand, $\phi'$ is continuous and does not vanish on the compact interval $[a,b]$. Therefore the function $\frac{1}{\phi'}$ is continuous, hence integrable, over $[a,b]$.

By the fact above,
$$
(f\circ \phi) \cdot\phi'\cdot\frac{1}{\phi'}=f\circ \phi
$$
is integrable over $[a,b]$.

**Note:** with Lebesgue integral and open intervals, this is no longer true. For instance, take $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ and $\phi(x)=x^2$ over $(0,1)$. Then $f$ is integrable, but $f\circ \phi$ is not, over $(0,1)$.

Comment: How do we know for sure that 1/phi' is integrable? x - 2 is integrable and continuous on a line of real numbers, but 1/x-2 is discontinuous at 2

Comment: @Amber Because $\phi'$ is never $0$, unlike $1/(x-2)$. So $1/\phi'$ is continuous on $[a,b]$.